# SVG images not displaying in table properly compared to other browsers

Tags: html, css, svg

I've created a simple table to display payment gateway icons on my website, works as expected on chrome/firefox/android

[image]

HTML / CSS:

```
<div id="draw-zone-wrapper" style="height: 25px;">
<table class="MyTable" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 18%;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://www.example.com/afterpay_logo.svg" /></td>
    <td style="width: 19%;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://www.example.com/klarna_logo.svg" /></td>
    <td style="width: 14%;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://www.example.com/zip_logo.svg" /></td>
    <td style="width: 21%;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://www.example.com/laybuy_logo.svg" /></td>
    <td style="width: 28%;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://www.example.com/latitude_logo.svg" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>


.MyTable td
{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Unfortunately IE does whatever it wants, and displays it like this:
[image]

Any suggestions on how I can improve what I've done so that all browsers play nicely?

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer doesn't apply any SVG clip to a html element, so you need an SVG `<image>` element instead of HTML `<img>` element and adjust the height and width of each SVG. Try it once

Comment: Newbie question, but with each SVG being a different width/height (and my wordpress theme being responsive) won't specifying the width/height break the responsiveness?

Comment: Yes and that's the problem with IE...you can put the same width and height to all SVGs. Or my one simple answer is "Just don't use IE"

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. You have to just add `max-width:100%;` to the `img`.

```
.MyTable img
{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Made no difference unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Since the width of images are different, you can try `max-height` for images like below. Also make sure that the svg image has viewBox defined.

```
.MyTable img {
    max-height: 30px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i checked and each image has a viewbox. By specifying a max height of 30px, that would result in the images being quite tiny on a 4k monitor?

Comment: @Embercide, you can target large screens with meida query and increase max-height for those screens.